# Facebook Graph API Search results limit

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I am using facebook graph api to do a search for the query "Restaurants in United Kingdom". But I am getting very limited set of results. If I do the same search with facebook UI, I am getting more results. 
Even if I try to access the next page using the pagination, I couldn't get more records. 
Is there a limit in the number of results based on my login/access token?  How to overcome this limitation?

I am doing a rest serach in Java using HttpGet with the following url

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/search?fields=name,likes,location,category,talking_about_count&type=page&q=Restaurants%20in%20United%20Kingdom&access_token=xxxxxx

Comment: how are you even still using this endpoint when it was deprecated?

Comment: What's the latest version to replace this? How to overcome this?